# OpenCV. How to connect to camera in VirtualBox

Tags: python, opencv, virtualbox, webcam

I have a Ubuntu vm in Oracle VirtualBox (Host: Mac OS X) with installed python (miniconda), opencv and built-in web camera connected to vm with Devices > Webcams menu.
If I try to test my webcam in sites like [this](https://www.onlinemictest.com/webcam-test/), it works good, but if I try to connect to camera with opencv from python in this way:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # or 1 or -1, I tried all
>>> ref, frame = cap.read()
>>> frame.shape
```

I have an error "NoneType has not attribute shape". How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your frame object is None i.e the function hasn't returned the object. First enable web cam feature in virtual box.

Comment: Refer this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129305/how-can-i-enable-access-to-usb-devices-within-virtualbox-guests

Comment: I enabled the camera in this way: go to Devices > Webcams menu, click on the HD-camera FaceTime, but it didn't help me. And I don't see my camera in USB devices

Comment: You are using the builtin camera or an external one?

Comment: I use built-in camera

Comment: If I try to write this command in vm in terminal: `ls /dev/video/*` I see a /dev/video0, if I understood all correctly, it means, that camera is connected.

Comment: Have you got `v4l2` (Video For Linux) installed?

Comment: Thank you. No, I'm going to try to install it and check.

Comment: I installed it, but cv2 couldn't connect to camera again.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, but requires a few steps to get working properly:

1.Make sure the virtual machine is not running and your webcam is not being used.

2.Bring up the main VBox window and in the details tab for your Win7 machine click USB.

3.Make sure "Enable USB Controller" is selected. Also make sure that "Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller" is selected too.

4.Click the "Add filter from device" button (the cable with the '+' icon).

5.Select your device from the list.

6.Now click OK and start your VM.

7. In terminal type `VBoxManage list webcams`. This will return the following output:

Video Input Devices: 1

.1 "FaceTime HD Camera"

0x8020000005ac8514

8. In terminal type `VboxManage controlvm "my_virtual_machine_name" webcam attach .1` . where `.1` is the designation of Virtualbox's `Video Input Devices`.

This will cause the device to show up as if it were plugged into the VM. From there, you should be able to use it or install drivers if necessary.

Comment: I don't see my built-in webcam in USB devices

Comment: Refer this https://askubuntu.com/questions/209950/integrated-webcam-cannot-be-used-in-virtualbox-guest-xp

Comment: It doesn't help me.

Comment: it saves my day, ... we have to run our VM before type in the command at number 8